# Indexing Special Terms Using Solr

Tags: solr, drupal-7

I'm currently using SOLR 5.2 on a drupal website. I have SOLR installed and works well. However when I have some content say for example an article that contains punctuation such as '/' in the title.

For example 16/11. (Many of my articles begin with the day/month). SOLR fails to index these items. Instead it strips the punctuation.

I have followed the following article: http://www.prowaveconsulting.com/indexing-special-terms-using-solr/

but haven't had much luck getting this to work. I need SOLR to index the punctuation. Mainly /!;,'"

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the **solr.WhiteSpaceTokenizer** instead of **StandardTokenizerFactory**.
   It will tokenize only on whitespaces "For example 16/11" -> tokens =  ["for","example","16/11"]
2. You can use **solr.PatternTokenizerFactory** with a pattern. It breaks the text at the specified regular expression pattern.

`<fieldType name="semicolonDelimited" class="solr.TextField">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern=";\s*" />
      </analyzer>
   </fieldType>`

3. You can write your own [custom tokenizer](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters)